# What is a natural operation?

Tags: group-theory

Let $(G_1, *_1) $ and $(G_2, *_2)$ be groups. Please provide a **natural** operation $*$ on $G = G_1 \times G_2$, so that $(G, *)$ is a group.

(Don't worry: I do not want you to do this exercise for me.)
I just need to know:

What is a natural [operation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_(mathematics))?

Comment: I suspect the exercise is just asking you to find a definition that seems sensible and straightforward. There is a technical sense in which the operation you are looking for is called natural in that it can be used to define what is called a functor on the category of groups, and this means that it behaves nicely with respect to group homomorphisms. If you haven't done any category theory, it must be the informal sense that is meant here.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is an operation induced by the given operations.

$$(a,b) * (c,d) := (a *_1c, b *_2d)$$

Comment: The OP asked for you to NOT just give the answer...

Comment: Then what should I answer him?

Comment: Thanks anyway. :D Why is $*$ now called *natural*?

Comment: I should really read more careful. Well it is most ''logical'' or ''natural'' way to define it.

Comment: @user1511417 Well, because it's the "natural", i.e., obvious thing to do.

Answer (score 0):

The operation is *categorically natural* because it gives $G_1 \times G_2$ the structure of a *product* in the category of groups.

More precisely, given any group $G$ with morphismos $p_1\colon G\to G_1$ and $p_2\colon G\to G_2$, there is *one and only one* morphism $\phi\colon G\to G_1\times G_2$ such that $\pi_1\circ\phi = p_1$ and $\pi_2\circ\phi = p_2$, where $\pi_i\colon G_1\times G_2\to G_i$ are the projections ($i=1,2$)